# How to add loop data to json object in CI?

Tags: javascript, php, json, codeigniter

I am trying to merge loop data to json object ,every time I am getting the last result of loop only ,so I declared that variable as a array ,its coming fine and I got my result but the format is not coming properly ,there is extra square brackets ,which I dont want ,because while parsing in front end ,its creating problem.

Below i am providing my codes.

```html
{

  "status": "success",
  "statusReason": "Favouritelist",
  "result": {
    "Favouritelist": [
      [ //want to remove this square bracket
        {
          "branch_id": "1234",
          "branch_name": "avis1",
          "branch_image": "uploads/avis.png",
          "branch_gps": "12.9250,77.5938",
          "branch_address": "eredfdf",
          "branch_phone": "2147483647",

        }
      ],//want to remove this square bracket
      [//want to remove this square bracket
        {
          "branch_id": "1234",
          "branch_name": "avis1",
          "branch_image": "uploads/avis.png",
          "branch_gps": "12.9250,77.5938",
          "branch_address": "eredfdf",
          "branch_phone": "2147483647",


        }
      ]//want to remove this square bracket
    ]
  }
}
```

My CI code

```html
foreach ($tempquery->result() as $res1){
         $car_id = $res1->car_id;  

       if(empty($timestamp)){

 $this->db->select("IFNULL(branch.branch_id,'') as branch_id,IFNULL(branch.name,'') as branch_name,IFNULL(branch.image,'') as branch_image,IFNULL(branch.gps,'') as branch_gps,IFNULL(branch.address,'')as branch_address,IFNULL(branch.phone,'')as branch_phone,(select IFNULL(avg(rating),0) from branch_rating where user_id='$user_id'  and delete_status ='false' )as branch_rating,IFNULL(car_id,'') as car_id,IFNULL(cars.name,'') as car_name,IFNULL(cars.image,'') as car_image,IFNULL(model,'') as model,IFNULL(price,'')as price,IFNULL(year,'')as year,IFNULL(type,'')as type,IFNULL(`no_of_seats`,'')as `no_of_seats`,IFNULL(`gear_type`,'') as `gear_type`,IFNULL(color,'') as color,insurance,status,IFNULL(description,'') as description,(select IFNULL(avg(rating),0) from car_rating where user_id='$user_id'  and delete_status ='false' )as car_rating,car_types.typename AS carType,cars.petrol_type,car_types.car_type_id,cars.delivery_charges,cars.services");
 $this->db->from("branch");
 $this->db->join("cars","branch.branch_id=cars.branch_id");
 $this->db->join('car_types', 'cars.car_type_id = car_types.car_type_id');
 $this->db->where("cars.car_id",$car_id);
 $this->db->where("branch.delete_status" , "false");
 $this->db->where("cars.delete_status" , "false");
$car_details= $this->db->get();  
 $cdetail_new[]=$car_details->result(); ///added [] to mearge dat


           }

 Response::code_200("Favouritelist", array("Favouritelist" => $cdetail_new));
```

Can any one suggest me ,where I am doing wrong..

Thank you in ADV

Comment: Try removing the `[]` from, like this `$cdetail_new=$car_details->result();` Will this work?

Comment: Format is coming fine but I am getting only the last row ,there are lots of result. @Praveen Kumar

Comment: Wow, this is crazy. Can you tell what's the `var_dump($car_details->result())`, may be the issue is at the source?

Comment: Try this? `$cdetail_new[] = $car_details->result()[0];` Gut feeling... `:)` This might work? If so, I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the source is packed with the array. The `result()` function here, perhaps gives it as an array?

```
$car_details->result();
```

If that's the case, you might want to unwrap it here. You can use this notation if you are using latest version of PHP:

```
$cdetail_new[] = $car_details->result()[0];
```

If not, try the older one:

```
$result = $car_details->result();
$cdetail_new[] = $result[0];
```

You can check if this is the issue or not, i.e., if the `result()` is giving output as an array with a single element by using:

```
$car_details = $this->db->get();
var_dump($car_details->result());  // Is this resulting as an array?
die();
$cdetail_new[] = $car_details->result(); ///added [] to mearge dat
```

Comment: ya I got this one $cdetail_new[] = $result[0];
I am using lowest version of php .So I used the second one.
Now its coming fine for me.Thank you a lot